# How to set HTTP method with ZPublisher.Client.call?

Tags: python, zope

I've tried calling Zope 2.10.9's `ZPublisher.Client.call` with the `method` argument to set the HTTP method (`GET`, `POST`, etc.), but it's not working as expected: It always sends a POST request. If I don't supply the `method` argument it always sends a GET request.

Application code:

```
Client.call(
    'http://...',
    username = 'jdoe',
    password = 'mypw',
    method = 'GET')
```

I've traced it a bit in [Client.py](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/blob/master/src/ZPublisher/Client.py):

```
def call(url,username=None, password=None, **kw):
    return apply(Function(url,username=username, password=password), (), kw)
```

OK, so `kw = { 'method': 'GET' }`. As far as I can tell this translates to

```
Function.__init__(
    'http://...',
    username = 'jdoe',
    password = 'mypw'
).__call__(
    method = 'GET')
```

`Function.__init__` expects `method` as part of its arguments but it's not passed there:

```
    def __init__(self,url,
                 arguments=(),method=None,username=None,password=None,
                 timeout=None,
                 **headers):
        ...
        if method is not None: self.method=method
```

`Function.__call__` expects `method` to be set already:

```
    def __call__(self,*args,**kw):
        method=self.method
```

**Should `call`'s signature and the `apply` call be modified to fit `__init__`, or am I misunderstanding something?** If it's really an error, here's a proposed patch (Works For Me™):

```
--- Client.py.orig
+++ Client.py
@@ -271,9 +271,9 @@

         return f

-def call(url,username=None, password=None, **kw):
+def call(url, arguments=(), method=None, username=None, password=None, timeout=None, **kw):

-    return apply(Function(url,username=username, password=password), (), kw)
+    return apply(Function(url, arguments=arguments, method=method, username=username, password=password, timeout=timeout), (), kw)

 ##############################################################################
 # Implementation details below here
```

[Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope2/+bug/1152193).

Answer (score 1):

The `ZPublisher.Client` module is really ancient, and should be considered unmaintained, really.

Yes, the `call()` function does not handle changing the `method`, and adding in method handling the way you suggest would work. The work-around would be to not use the `call()` function but instead use the `Function()` class directly.

Feel free to add the patch to the [Zope issue tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope/+bugs).